# S3ResponseError: 403 Forbidden.An error occurred (NoSuchKey) when calling the GetObject operation: The specified key does not exist

Tags: amazon-s3, boto, boto3

```
try:

  conn = boto.connect_s3(access_key,secret_access_key)
  bucket = conn.get_bucket(bucket_name, validate=False)
  k1 = Key(bucket)
  k1.key = 'Date_Table.csv'

  # k = bucket.get_key('Date_Table.csv')
  k1.make_public()
  k1.get_contents_to_filename(tar)

except Exception as e:
  print(e)
```

i am getting error

> S3ResponseError: 403 Forbidden 
>   `AccessDenied`Access
>   DeniedD9ED8BFF6D6A993Eaw0KmxskATNBTDUEo3SZdwrNVolAnrt9/pkO/EGlq6X9Gxf36fQiBAWQA7dBSjBNZknMxWDG9GI=

i tried all posibility and still getting same error .. please guide me how to solve this issue.

i tried other way as below and getting error

> An error occurred (NoSuchKey) when calling the GetObject operation:
>   The specified key does not exist.

```
session = boto3.session.Session(aws_access_key_id=access_key, aws_secret_access_key=secret_access_key,region_name='us-west-2')
    print ("session:"+str(session)+"\n")
    client = session.client('s3', endpoint_url=s3_url)
    print ("client:"+str(client)+"\n")
    stuff = client.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key='Date_Table.csv')
    print ("stuff:"+str(stuff)+"\n")
    stuff.download_file(local_filename)
```

ge

Answer (score 0):

Always use boto3. boto is deprecated.

1. As long as you setup AWS CLI credential, you don't need to pass the hard-coded credential. Read [boto3 credential setup](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/configuration.html) throughly.
2. There is no reason to initiate boto3.session unless you are using different region and user profile.
3. Take your time and study difference between service client(boto3.client) vs service resources(boto3.resources).
4. Low level boto3.client is easier to use for experiments. Use high level boto3.resource if you need to pass around arbitrary object.

Here is the simple code for [boto3.client("s3").download_file](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.download_file).

```
import boto3 
# initiate the proper AWS services client, i.e. S3 
s3 = boto3.client("s3")
s3.download_file('your_bucket_name', 'Date_Table.csv', '/your/local/path/and/filename')
```